# Django return two variables (one related) in for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2, django-queryset

I'm building a school schedule management system
With this system, someone can select a module and see the the teachers available on that day and what other classes they have at this specific day.

So for example, if someone clicks "Maths", you will see the following:

```
teacher_name1 - Date: 20/2/2022
Other classes on the same day: Physics, History

teacher_name2 - Date: 20/2/2022
Other classes on the same day: None
```

I can get the first part of when someone clicks the module, to get a list of teachers for a specific date, but I cannot get the rest of the modules that the teacher is having on the same day

My models are the following:

```
class Available_Module(models.Model):
    module_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=False, null=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=False, null=True)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    calendar_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="available_teacher")
    module = models.ForeignKey(Available_Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="module_item")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Below the views.py:

```
def teachers_listing(request, module_slug, **date_filters):
    module = Available_Module.objects.get(slug=module_slug)
    get_module_id = Available_Module.objects.get(slug = clinic_slug).id
    default_date = today
    recent_dates = Schedule.objects.order_by('calendar_date').distinct('calendar_date').filter(calendar_date__range = (today, date_range))
    date_filters = recent_dates
    available_teachers = Schedule.objects.filter(module=get_module_id, calendar_date=default_date).order_by('module')
    return render(request, 'schedule_core/available_teachers.html', {
        'available_teachers': available_teachers,
        'module': module,
        'date_filters': date_filters,
        'module_slug': module_slug
    })
```

So as I mentioned when someone clicks on a module, I want them to see the teacher, the module they selected and what other modules the teacher has on the same day.
However I cannot return the rest of the modules that the teacher is having.

```
{% for available_teacher in available_teachers %}
<li>{{ available_teacher.teacher }} - Date: {{ available_teacher.calendar_date | date:"M-d" }}</li>
<p>Other classes on the same day:</p> <!-- Here I cannot get the part of the rest of the modules that the teacher is having on the same day-->
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks a lot for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but a simple suggestion to retrieve all the modules of the available teachers is:

```
# Return all teachers teaching this module
available_teachers = Schedule.objects.filter(module=module).values('teacher').distinct()
# All other modules
modules = Schedule.objects.filter(teacher__in=available_teachers).exclude(module=module)
```

The `exclude` part is to get the "rest" of the modules other than the one that the user clicked on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How may I be able to then add it in the templates for loop?

Comment: Just as you use them in the code you added in the question, pass it to the context, and loop the objects, then you can use `schedule.teacher.teacher_name` for example.

Comment: Thanks again! I got what you mean.. I'm getting the full list but it's not the expected output. It returns indeed the teachers and all classes, but in the loop that I'm doing, I'm seeing multiple times the same teacher for each module.
What I'm trying to achieve is to get one time the teacher and in the same loop to show the modules that he/she has